# Apply UDF function to Spark window where the input paramter is a list of all column values in range

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to build a moving average on each row in a window. Let's say -10 rows. BUT if there are less than 10 rows available I would like to insert a 0 in the resulting row -> new column.
So what I would try to achieve is using a UDF in an aggregate window with input paramter List()  (or whatever superclass) which has the values of all rows available.

Here's a code example that doesn't work:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("id").rowsBetween(-10, +0)
dfRetail2.withColumn("test", udftestf(dfRetail2("salesMth")).over(w))
```

`Expected output: List( 1,2,3,4)` if no more rows are available and take this as input paramter for the udf function. udf function should return a calculated value or 0 if less than 10 rows available.

the above code terminates: `Expression 'UDF(salesMth#152L)' not supported within a window function.;;`

Comment: While browsing the net for answers I found this: "User defined Aggregate functions UDAF" instead of UDF. This might be it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spark's built-in Window functions along with `when/otherwise` for your specific condition without the need of UDF/UDAF.  For simplicity, the sliding-window size is reduced to 4 in the following example with dummy data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._

val df = (1 to 2).flatMap(i => Seq.tabulate(8)(j => (i, i * 10.0 + j))).
  toDF("id", "amount")

val slidingWin = 4

val winSpec = Window.partitionBy($"id").rowsBetween(-(slidingWin - 1), 0)

df.
  withColumn("slidingCount", count($"amount").over(winSpec)).
  withColumn("slidingAvg", when($"slidingCount" < slidingWin, 0.0).
    otherwise(avg($"amount").over(winSpec))
  ).show
// +---+------+------------+----------+
// | id|amount|slidingCount|slidingAvg|
// +---+------+------------+----------+
// |  1|  10.0|           1|       0.0|
// |  1|  11.0|           2|       0.0|
// |  1|  12.0|           3|       0.0|
// |  1|  13.0|           4|      11.5|
// |  1|  14.0|           4|      12.5|
// |  1|  15.0|           4|      13.5|
// |  1|  16.0|           4|      14.5|
// |  1|  17.0|           4|      15.5|
// |  2|  20.0|           1|       0.0|
// |  2|  21.0|           2|       0.0|
// |  2|  22.0|           3|       0.0|
// |  2|  23.0|           4|      21.5|
// |  2|  24.0|           4|      22.5|
// |  2|  25.0|           4|      23.5|
// |  2|  26.0|           4|      24.5|
// |  2|  27.0|           4|      25.5|
// +---+------+------------+----------+
```

Per remark in the comments section, I'm including a solution via UDF below as an alternative:

```
def movingAvg(n: Int) = udf{ (ls: Seq[Double]) =>
  val (avg, count) = ls.takeRight(n).foldLeft((0.0, 1)){
    case ((a, i), next) => (a + (next-a)/i, i + 1) 
  }
  if (count <= n) 0.0 else avg  // Expand/Modify this for specific requirement
}

// To apply the UDF:
df.
  withColumn("average", movingAvg(slidingWin)(collect_list($"amount").over(winSpec))).
  show
```

Note that unlike `sum` or `count`, `collect_list` ignores `rowsBetween()` and generates partitioned data that can potentially be very large to be passed to the UDF (hence the need for `takeRight()`).  If the computed Window `sum` and `count` are sufficient for what's needed for your specific requirement, consider passing them to the UDF instead.

---

In general, especially if the data at hand is already in DataFrame format, it'd perform and scale better by using built-in DataFrame API to take advantage of Spark's execution engine optimization than using user-defined UDF/UDAF.  You might be interested in reading this [article](https://medium.com/teads-engineering/spark-performance-tuning-from-the-trenches-7cbde521cf60) re: advantages of DataFrame/Dataset API over UDF/UDAF.

Comment: Clear and crisp scala code. Did the trick. Thanks much! One question. I think it would have worked with a UDAF as well but with way more code. Does this solution mean that I can just work with UDF and no need to bother with UDAF?

Comment: @Sven, there is actually no need for UDF or UDAF.  Please see my simplified solution.

Comment: Thanks much.I have to admit that my example with 0 was too simple (because it is out of scope for the question being asked). My evaluation is a bit more complicated so I 'd rather use the udf solution. Can I rephrase? So with the udf solution can I get around ever using a UDAF. UDAF are more complex as you have to create a new (case) class per function. Or is there a use case where I would need them - just being curious.

Comment: @Sven, please see my expanded answer.